# Failing Unions due to Non-Noded Intersections

Tags: shapely, geopandas, topology, snapping, union

I'm trying to perform lots of unions in GeoPandas. I've got around fifty sets of between 7-12 GeoDataFrames of the same place at different times that I'm trying to union into one layer per set. Right now, about 20% of the unions are failing due to non-noded intersection exceptions. I'm not sure why snapping the layers doesn't solve this issue. The union looks like this:

```py
# Snap the add layer to the base
flat = flatten(base)
add.geometry  = [snap(g, flat, 0.0001) for g in add.geometry]
base.geometry = [snap(g, flat, 0.0001) for g in base.geometry]

# Ensure the geometries are still 
add  = ensureValid(add)
base = ensureValid(base)

# Union the add layer to the base
base= gpd.overlay(add, base, "union")
```

Here are the helper functions:

```
def flatten(gdf):

    # Try performing a unary union
    try:
        flat = unary_union(gdf)

    except:

        # Try performing a unary union with buffers
        try:
            flat = unary_union(gdf.buffer(0.00001).buffer(-0.00001))

        # Break the MultiPolygons down into LineStrings and do the unary union on those
        except:
            lines = []
            for f in mapping(ensureValid(gdf).geometry)["features"]:
                 coords = json.loads(json.dumps(f["geometry"]["coordinates"]))
                 cpairs = []
                 for a in range(len(coords)):
                     for b in range(len(coords[a][0])):
                         cpairs.append(tuple(coords[a][0][b]))
                 lines.append(LineString(cpairs))
            flat = unary_union(lines)

    # Return the result
    return flat
```

and

```
def ensureValid(gdf, geom_type=MultiPolygon):

    # See if there are invalid geometries
    if len(gdf[~gdf.is_valid]):

        # Use a zero buffer to fix problematic intersections
        gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda g: g.buffer(0.0) if not g.is_valid else g)

        # Remove remaining invalid geometries because I have no idea how to fix them
        gdf = gdf.loc[gdf.is_valid & ~gdf.is_empty]

    # Ensure that every geometry has the correct type
    gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda g: geom_type([g]) if type(g) != geom_type else g)

    return gdf
```

Relevant imports:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import json, shapely
from shapely.geometry import mapping, LineString
from shapely.geometry.multipolygon import MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import snap, unary_union
```

Traceback:

```
    base = gpd.overlay(add, base, "union")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 371, in overlay
    result = _overlay_union(df1, df2)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 299, in _overlay_union
    dfsym = _overlay_symmetric_diff(df1, df2)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 273, in _overlay_symmetric_diff
    dfdiff1 = _overlay_difference(df1, df2)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 260, in _overlay_difference
    [geom] + list(df2.geometry.iloc[neighbours]))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopandas\tools\overlay.py", line 259, in <lambda>
    new = reduce(lambda x, y: x.difference(y).buffer(0),

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 616, in difference
    return geom_factory(self.impl['difference'](self, other))

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py", line 70, in __call__
    self._check_topology(err, this, other)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\topology.py", line 39, in _check_topology
    raise err

TopologicalError: This operation could not be performed. Reason: unknown
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: have you tried makeValid?

Comment: @ElioDiaz Is that possible to do from inside my Python script?

Comment: reading on makeValid I found it is included (I've used it) in pyqgis dir(QgsVectorLayer); it is a function from postgis, also included in R (I've also used that one); I thought it would be available for geopandas or shapely, there's a function on the web, https://github.com/ftwillms/makevalid which I haven't tried

Comment: @ElioDiaz I've now tried makeValid and it hasn't solved the issue. The problem doesn't appear to be with either gdf before the overlay, but rather from a non-noded intersection appearing during the Difference portion of the union. I posted the traceback in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! There were two issues.

1. The geometries I was trying to put in were not all valid. Huge thanks to @ElioDiaz for finding a version of ST_MakeValid that I could easily include in my script. While the buffer(0) trick works sometimes, the makevalid git repository is a lot more effective. I still had to drop a bunch of invalid geometries, but I think that it's fine for my purposes.
2. Some of the coordinates created after the unions were not rounded to the correct precision. Although I had rounded them to 1m (0.00001) before, any points that were created during the union were not rounded. Rounding the coordinates again solved the issue.